# path.plot in R synth package not plotting over whole time period

Tags: r

I have used the synth package to generate the dataprep.out and synth.out objects for plotting. However, when I use the path.plot function, the graph defaults to just the post-treatment period.

```html
path.plot(
  synth.res = synth.out, 
  dataprep.res = dataprep.out,
  Ylab = "black mortality rate (per 100000) among 80-84 yos", 
  Xlab = "year", 
  Legend = c("Iowa", "synthetic Iowa"), 
  Legend.position = "bottomright"
  )
```

[default plot: just post-treatment period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFcV.png)

When I adjust the Z.plot parameter, only the pre-treatment period is plotted.

```html
path.plot(
  synth.res = synth.out, 
  dataprep.res = dataprep.out,
  Ylab = "black mortality rate (per 100000) among 80-84 yos", 
  Xlab = "year", 
  Legend = c("Iowa", "synthetic Iowa"), 
  Legend.position = "bottomright",
  Z.plot = TRUE
  )
```

[plot specifying Z.plot parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0G1F.png)

I'd be extremely grateful if anyone could identify why this might be happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but thought I'd answer in case it is helpful for others. Be sure to specify the time.plot term in the dataprep() to be the full time period, not just the post-treatment period.